# empty unwanted vertical space between tables

Tags: html, html-table

Well i have something strange.
2 tables should diretly follow each other
there is nothing in between   so the new table should directly start.
However some pages show an empty line between them while others do not.

Both pages have the same html header, same doc style, charset..
And no css styles do aply to these tables.
each table starts as

```
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" celspacing="0">
```

Here is a page with the conflict :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Sapec ontwikkeld vision toepassing in industrie</title>
<?php  // writing the page menu on top
  include './BaseTemplate.php';
  WriteHeader();
?>

</head>
<body>
<div id="background"><img src="./assets/image/background2.jpg" width="640" height="400" class="stretch" /></div>
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" >

<?php
 WriteMenu();
?>
</table>
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" >
<tr><td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" colspan="2" valign="top" >
```

And here is a page that doesnt show the conflict, note that for both these pages the php code outputs exactly the same so that isnt realy relevant.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Contact </title>

<?php  // writing the page menu on top
  include './BaseTemplate.php';
  WriteHeader();
?>

</head>
<body>
<div id="background"><img src="./assets/image/background2.jpg" width="640"  height="400" class="stretch" /></div>
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" >

<?php
  WriteMenu();
?>
</table>
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" >
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" width="45%" valign="bottom"  >
```

Comment: try to update the cellpadding="10" to cellpadding="0"

Comment: "cellspacing" is misspelt. Can you post the code that comes immediately before the tables, since this is likely causing the problem.

Comment: Also the seccond example works well with cellpadding = 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventualy it turned out that because of a php part contained some wrong formating, not everthing was included inside the  parts some where before it, this caused malformatted tables.

I just mark this as answer although the code wasnt in this part, but its solved now, so people wont need to post to this question or think about it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Change your cellpadding to

```
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" celspacing="0">
```

Comment: that was actually a typing error when i typed it into stackoverflow

Comment: and cellpadding reffers to inner table border distance to text, its not related to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Check its not some inherited margin/padding

```
table{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```